# How to sort a category list array alphabetically in Magento

Tags: php, magento

In Magento, I've created a phtml template file with the code below. I got this [from this tutorial](http://www.devinrolsen.com/magento-custom-category-listing-block/). Me and others are wondering how to sort this category list alphabetically. The first lines of code create an array with Category IDs. Further down, we can get the Category Name using the ID within the foreach section. But to sort by Name, we need to get the Names in an array before the foreach and then sort by name. How?

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(319)->getChildren();
$catIds = explode(',',$cats);
?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($catIds as $catId): ?>
    <li>
        <?php
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
            echo '<a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">';
            echo $category->getName() . '</a>';
        ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

*Note: 319 is the category id of the parent category for which I want to list subcategories. Also, I'm not putting this is a category page template. I'm inserting as a block in a CMS page (that part is already working).*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could build a list of category names first.

```
<?php
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(319)->getChildren();
$catIds = explode(',',$cats);

$categories = array();
foreach($catIds as $catId) {
       $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
       $categories[$category->getName()] = $category->getUrl();
}

ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach($categories as $name => $url): ?>
    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I wrote this answer without knowing too much about Magento and just wanting something quickly that worked. [Anton's answer is better and more Magentic(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4274820/31671)

Comment: I just tested that... the sort order was the same. If I use krsort, then order is correct, but I'm not sure if that makes sense. It should sort alphabetically on the name, but ksort sorts id desc. thoughts?

Comment: asort works instead of rsort! How did you write that so fast, btw? It was literally minutes after I posted it!

Comment: Just used your answer for what I was trying to achieve and works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: The (higher rated) answers below didn't work for me! Thanks for this answer :)

Answer (score 22):

You can call

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', '319')->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

and you'll get the whole bunch sorted right away, rest is just iteration over typical Varien collection. It's a pseudo sample and i don't know if the parent_id is the actual field name in db so you might check that out before you get the right results.

[Great read about collections in Magento is written by Alan Storm](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections)

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC') is the best method to use.

Comment: It is a great answer. It didn't work for me, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am using magento 1.4.1.1 and this worked to sort the child categories:
use

```
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(319)->getChildrenCategories();
```

to get the children categories of category with id 319
and edit the file at `code/core/Mage/catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/category.php` at line 582 under the function `getChildrenCategories()` to change

```
->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

to

```
->setOrder('name','ASC);
```

hope this works for you too.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please use the formatting buttons provided in the editor.

Comment: `->setOrder('name','ASC);` should be `->setOrder('name','ASC');`. Note the missing `'` :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way to do this in the latest Magento (CE 1.7.0.2)+

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(319, 1, true, true);

// iterate through the results
foreach ($children as $category):
    echo '<option value="' . $category->getUrl() . '">' . $category->getName() . '</option>';
endforeach;
```

The function `getChildren()` resides at...

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php around line 817`

There are loads of options. Hope it saves you some time!

Comment: Nice and simple! This answer deserves a lot more credit!

Answer (score 1):

First backup your topmenu.phtml then replace the following code in your new topmenu.phtml file

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php

function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC){
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
            asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
            arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}

?>
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
    <?php if (count($_categories) > 0){ ?>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category){ ?>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><span><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></span></a>
            <?php $catList = array();?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subCategory){ ?>
                <?php $catList[] = array('name' => $_subCategory->getName(), 'url' => $_subCategory->getUrl(), 'id' => $_subCategory->getId());?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php $catList = array_sort($catList, 'name', SORT_ASC);?>
            <ul>
            <?php if (count($catList) > 0){ ?>
                <?php $subcat=0?>
                <?php foreach($catList as $_subCategory){ ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $_subCategory['url'] ?>"><span><?php echo $_subCategory['name'] ?></span></a>
                    <?php $subCatList = array();?>
                    <?php $_subSubCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subCategory['id']);
                    $_subSubCategories = $_subSubCat->getChildrenCategories();?>
                    <?php foreach($_subSubCategories as $_subSubCategory){ ?>
                        <?php $subCatList[] = array('name' => $_subSubCategory['name'], 'url' => $_subSubCategory['url']);?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php $subCatList = array_sort($subCatList, 'name', SORT_ASC);?>
                    <?php if (count($subCatList) > 0){ ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($subCatList as $_subSubCat){ ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $_subSubCat['url'] ?>"><span><?php echo $_subSubCat['name'] ?></span></a>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that I accidentally down-voted this answer and up-voted only because I do not have an option to remove the vote.