# Sort Magento Product Collection by Category

Tags: magento

I have a category structure like that:

```
Root Cat
  Sub Cat 1
  Sub Cat 2
  Sub Cat 3
```

and a product collection:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
```

Now I would like to sort the products in the collection by category. Sub Cat 1 products should come first, then Sub Cat 2 products and finally Sub Cat 3 products. If I change the order of the categories, the order of the products in the collection should change, too. How can I achieve that? A simple `$productCollection->addAttributeToSort('category');` or `$productCollection->setOrder('category')` does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273898/how-to-sort-a-category-list-array-alphabetically-in-magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve all the functionality you want by simply modifying the collection. `category` isn't an attribute. `category_ids` is, but when I tried sorting on it it had no effect.

I would get the categories (in the order you want), then get the products from those categories using the `addCategoryFilter()` function.

Example:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getId() . ':' . PHP_EOL;
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addCategoryFilter($category);
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // Do something
        echo '  ' . $product->getSku() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nachito! I hoped that there is a native way to do it (mainly for performance reasons), but probably there is not...