# Change Magento Menu Subcategory Sort Order

Tags: php, magento, menu

I am using the following code to display Categories and Subcategories in a drop down menu, however I want the subcategories to be sorted alphabetically... how can I do this?

```
<ul id="custom-menu">
<li><a href="http://www.mobiledistributorsupply.com"><b>Home</b></a></li>
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<ul style="width:940px;">
    <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <li>
<b><a class="drop" href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
            </a></b>
<?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                <div class="dropdown_1column" style="width:235px;">
                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <div class="col_1">
                     <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <div class="clr" clear="all"></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<li class="normal"><a href="/products/onsale"><b>Sale</b></a></li>
<li class="normal"><a href="/customer-service"><b>Help</b></a></li>
<li class="normal"><a href="/customer/account/create/"><b>Open Account</b></a></li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've always done as our clients don't usually have categories that change frequently is dragged and dropped them in alphabetical order in the admin backend: `Catalog > Categories > Manage Categories`.

If that's not your style, you can always take some advice from this answer to first run through the categories, place them in a new array, and then key sort the array and finally output: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4273912/823549

Answer (score -1):

First backup your topmenu.phtml then replace the following code in your new topmenu.phtml file

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php

function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC){
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
            asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case SORT_DESC:
            arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}

?>
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
    <?php if (count($_categories) > 0){ ?>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category){ ?>
            <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><span><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></span></a>
            <?php $catList = array();?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subCategory){ ?>
                <?php $catList[] = array('name' => $_subCategory->getName(), 'url' => $_subCategory->getUrl(), 'id' => $_subCategory->getId());?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php $catList = array_sort($catList, 'name', SORT_ASC);?>
            <ul>
            <?php if (count($catList) > 0){ ?>
                <?php $subcat=0?>
                <?php foreach($catList as $_subCategory){ ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $_subCategory['url'] ?>"><span><?php echo $_subCategory['name'] ?></span></a>
                    <?php $subCatList = array();?>
                    <?php $_subSubCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subCategory['id']);
                    $_subSubCategories = $_subSubCat->getChildrenCategories();?>
                    <?php foreach($_subSubCategories as $_subSubCategory){ ?>
                        <?php $subCatList[] = array('name' => $_subSubCategory['name'], 'url' => $_subSubCategory['url']);?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php $subCatList = array_sort($subCatList, 'name', SORT_ASC);?>
                    <?php if (count($subCatList) > 0){ ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($subCatList as $_subSubCat){ ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $_subSubCat['url'] ?>"><span><?php echo $_subSubCat['name'] ?></span></a>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```