# Sort topmenu in Magento?

Tags: magento, sorting, menu

This is really driving me crazy. I have been trying for hours to get it right, but no luck!
All i want is to be able to sort the parent & subcategories in the topmenu of Magento. I tried a lot of custom coding, but all what Ive found seems to be out of date. Then i also tried to just move the categories order in the admin panel of Magento. This seems to work, but only for parent categories. It won't sort the subcategories. In addition, for some strange reason it will put the old order back again. So for instance, when i sorted the parent categories, it seems to work but when i refresh the admin page the old sorted categories are back and when i refresh the frontpage i see (indeed) the old (wrong) sorted categories back. Might have something to do with the cache ? It should be so simple (i hope:)). Is there anyone who can tell me how i can sort the categories and subcategories (custom, or by id, or anything else...)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel these urls will help you in this case

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/getting_and_using_categories_and_subcategories

[How to sort a category list array alphabetically in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273898/how-to-sort-a-category-list-array-alphabetically-in-magento/4273912#4273912)

Comment: I found out that there is also an order option per category, that pretty much helped me out! thanks!